# HTTPS headless browser to HTTP localhost Flask

Tags: design, python, http, docker, flask

I have two Docker containers:

1. Headless browser grabbing images by running JavaScript
2. Flask server analysing these images (and sending results to another server)

I'm using a bridge network to communicate, but I'm running into a lot of problems:

1. Flask is HTTP, headless grabs from an HTTPS website, causing "mixed content" errors
2. Change the call and the Flask server to HTTPS with ad-hoc SSL, which gives me ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
3. [Add  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48700852/2208827) gives me net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This feels too complicated to send an extracted image from a headless browser to another Docker container. Is there a different way I can design this to prevent these HTTP/HTTPS call workarounds altogether?

Comment: can you use something other than HTTP(S) to communicate between your browser and your analyzer?

Comment: I'm in full control of the headless browser with the JS and the Flask app, so I could use pretty much anything I guess, what alternatives should I look at?

Comment: well what does your headless browser have access to? can it save files? open sockets?

Comment: I have solved the problem using 2.adhoc SSL with an added flag --ignore-certificate-errors for the headless browser, but I still don't know what the best practice is. I could open sockets, that looks cleaner already. What is the impact of using sockets vs. HTTP in terms of performance?